# Export JavaFX project as an executable file that opens with two clicks

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx, executable-jar, java-14

I want to export my JavaFX project as an executable file that starts with two clicks.

I do not want my users to have to configure or download anything to run the application.

---

Please describe everything **step** **by** **step**.

---

- Use of:

> **Java SE 14.0.2**
>
> **IntelliJ IDEA**

Comment: a new round of jpackage related questions, with yet another account?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [what's on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and read [How to Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Note that Stack Overflow is place to ask a specific question based on your own attempts to solve a task or problem. Asking others here to write up a complete guide is not a suitable question as it is too broad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a detailed tutorial for this. https://github.com/dlemmermann/JPackageScriptFX It uses the new jpackage tool together with jdeps and jlink to achieve what you want. Warning. I am biased though because I am the co-author of this tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

**Deploying JavaFX Applications**

https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/self-contained-packaging.htm

Comment: Thanks, but this is an outdated document. I want to export my JavaFX project as an executable file that starts with two clicks. I do not want my users to have to configure or download anything to run the application.